# Find next element above with class

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of element with the class price if the quantity is clicked. I continue to get undefined with next() ,find(), closest(). Its at the point that asking should be faster.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input.quantity').click(function() {
    var test = $(this).parent('.qty-price').closest('.price').html();
    alert(test);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="product">
  <a href="/" class="product-link">
    <span class="product-details">
                <h3>Test Description</h3>
                <span class="qty-price">
                    <span class="qty">
                        <input type="number" rel="0" class="form-control text-center quantity" value="1"  min="0">
                    </span>
    <span class="price">$5.00</span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </a>
  <a href="#remove" class="remove-button"><span class="remove-icon">X</span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Click events don't fire on disabled inputs and spans don't have a value property, so `.val()` won't work

Comment: The disabled form control was a mistake for this example. The actual control is not disabled. I understand now that val(), but html() doesn't work either. Just trying to get that display value. I think the point, is that I'm not getting to that element properly. Code has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your input isn't disabled as you said in your comment you can use the following. Note that since your input lies within an anchor you need to stop the click event from bubbling up the DOM.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input.quantity').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var test = $(this).parent('.qty').next('.price').text();
    alert(test);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="product">
  <a href="/" class="product-link">
    <span class="product-details">
                <h3>Test Description</h3>
                <span class="qty-price">
                    <span class="qty">
                        <input type="number" rel="0" class="form-control text-center quantity" value="1"  min="0" >
                    </span>
    <span class="price">$5.00</span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </a>
  <a href="#remove" class="remove-button"><span class="remove-icon">X</span></a>
</li>
```